# Specify the time of daily log rotate

Tags: 10.04, server, logrotate

I noticed that daily log rotations which are listed under `/etc/logrotate.d/` are executed in the morning around 6:40 am. This is clear from the beginning and ending of the log files. Can I customize this time and set it to midnight for example?

It is nice to have one log file per day.

I am using ubuntu server 10.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Edit in `/etc/crontab` the line that says

```bsh
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

so that the `25 6` reads `0 0`. This will make it so that all scripts in `/etc/cron.daily` runs at midnight.

If you only want to make logrotate run at midnight, move `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` to some other directory, and add the line

```bsh
0 0    * * *   root    /new/path/to/logrotate/script
```

at the end of `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: You might also want to make corresponding changes to the weekly and monthly lines in the same file.  I'm guessing that keeping them in the same relative order (daily, weekly, monthly) and spacing is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Webmin/Virtualmin installed on your server you can change your logrotate execution time easier:

Just go to `Webmin -> Scheduled Cron Jobs` and  Select daily cron. Modify it as you want and save it.