# Make the daily log rotate run on exact time

Tags: 12.04, cron, time, logrotate

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS server.

My daily log rotations which are listed under `/etc/logrotate.d/` are executed at the morning around 7:00 am, but it is not on exact time, each day it changed on range of (07:00 - 07:25), How can I prevent the random time execution of log rotation?

`/etc/crontab` file content:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

\# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
0 7     * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` content:

```
\#!/bin/sh

\# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
      [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Related thread:
[Specify the time of daily log rotate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24503/specify-the-time-of-daily-log-rotate)

Comment: See also [cron-job-every-day-at-specific-minute-of-specific-hour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736236/cron-job-every-day-at-specific-minute-of-specific-hour)

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/cron.daily` folder contains dozens of items (17 items in my box), and `logrotate` is not guaranteed to run at first.

So if you want `logrotate` to run exactly the same time everyday, make it as a single entry in the `crontab` as in the Related thread: [Specify the time of daily log rotate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24503/specify-the-time-of-daily-log-rotate)