# Cron job every day at Specific Minute of Specific Hour

Tags: 14.04, cron, time

I am trying to set a cron job in the crontab which would execute my command every day at specific minute of specific hour. I am using the Indian timezone in my server.

If I set the job like below, well ... it executes at specific minute in every hour:

```
30 * * * * COMMAND
```

But if I set the job like below, it doesn't execute:

```
30 15 * * * COMMAND  # not excecuting
```

Why it is not executing? Where is the problem?

Comment: Given the CRON job starting at 2016-02-18 13:50:05 (now), it would run: 2016-02-18 15:30:00, 2016-02-19 15:30:00, 2016-02-20 15:30:00...

Comment: Check the logs for more detail _/var/log/syslog_ _grep CRON /var/log/syslog_

Comment: @RameshChand You need a `|` in there somewhere I think. Also that doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a cron job like:

```
30 00,01,02,....23 * * * COMMAND
```

where you  can specify your desired hours as 00,01,02,...23 (separating them with a comma).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similar problem.

The syntax of cron definition is correct.

The problem could be with timezone. **If you changed the timezone of your server**, and didn't restart the cron service, maybe this is the problem.

Just execute: `sudo service cron restart`, and maybe it could work.