# Run cron at specific minute and hour

Tags: cron

Ubuntu 16.04 here. Is this (supposed to be) possible?

```
12 23 * * 1-5 command
```

It doesn't work and it looks like a bug, but I'm starting to doubt myself because I can't believe something this crucial would be a bug. I do not ask this question lightly, because it took me 2 months of blaming myself and changing the jobs to conclude that it simply doesn't work.

This works, executing every minute at 11 PM:

```
* 23 * * 1-5 command
```

This works too, executing 12 minutes past every hour:

```
12 * * * 1-5 command
```

This seems like a similar question for Ubuntu 14.04 with no viable answers: [Cron job every day at Specific Minute of Specific Hour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736236/cron-job-every-day-at-specific-minute-of-specific-hour)

I made a [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/1657592), but for some reason I'm half expecting someone to point out it's my own fault.

**Full disclosure**

I resorted to pushbullet for testing, like so:

```
12 23 * * 1-5 curl -su MyApiKeyHere: https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -d type=note -d title="`hostname`" -d body="PING" 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

**Update**

It seems that minutes past the half hour are working:

```
12 23 * * 1-5 command # does not work
45 23 * * 1-5 command # works
```

This is... difficult stuff.

Comment: Very strange indeed, I have tested with this version of cron and it runs fine.

Comment: I also tested your scenario, using the same version of cron and it worked fine.

Comment: @squarebear @doug That is so weird. Is there a way to print the values `cron` uses for the asteriks(*)? Maybe I should create a massive cron with every hour and every minute and write outputs to logs and see which ones are missing. **Note** that I'm not logged in during these cron jobs, so `home` is locked/encrypted. It didn't seem relevant but I shouldn't make any educated assumptions.

Comment: I don't know about ways to print values for *. Perhaps tell us your methods. I did two methods: Edited /etc/crontab (but added the required user field); Did crontab -e as me, doug. Both methods worked fine. Do you do something different? Your encrypted home might well be relevant. (Note that I don't get notified if you don't get my name right.)

Comment: On a newly installed system (Debian 10), after changing the time zone (with timedatectl) I had exactly the same problems - I ended up finding that cron still worked with the old time zone. By restarting the cron service (systemctl restart cron) the problem was solved.