# how to make logrotate.d daily rotate each day at 00:00 exactly

Tags: 16.04, cron, logrotate

I've followed the method shown at https://askubuntu.com/a/24526/498355 to make daily logrotate.d rotate at exactly 00:00. I have 2 physical servers which ubuntu 16.04 with the same date and timezone. The problem is that one server rotates on 01:00 and the other on 00:00.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Are the two servers in sync timewise?

Comment: Yes. Server 1: `Thu Aug  4 12:41:37 EEST 2016`, server 2: `Thu Aug  4 12:41:37 EEST 2016`.

Comment: What happens if you specify 00 23 * * * for the one that starts at 1am?
Alternatively don't use the numerical method, use "@midnight"
See here at the bottom of the page for "@" options.
https://linuxmoz.com/crontab-syntax-tutorial/